# Merge five Gmail accounts into one new Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have five Gmail accounts that I have created over the years and am beyond tired of checking all of them.  I would like to combine all five together into one and delete all of the old accounts. I know I can get all of them into one account and check all emails using one account, but I want to only have ONE account PERIOD. I have identical contacts in each account and I want to only have them listed ONE time in ONE place.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would set them all up to forward to the main account that you wish to keep. Then any mail sent to any of those accounts would only go to the one that you'll be checking every day. Thus, all of your contacts would be in the same place and people who may not have an updated record of your main email address would still be able to reach you.

[See this link from google on how to do this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en)